# Select from two tables and order by datetime stamps

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have two MySQL tables similar to below:

```
MESSAGES_IN
messageID
receivedDate
message

MESSAGES_OUT
messageID
sentDate
message
```

Basically, I want to select messages from both tables and order them by their respective dates.  For example, if the data set were:

```
MESSAGES_IN
1  2014-04-24 12:26:33  Test message inbound
2  2014-04-24 19:12:15  Another test message inbound

MESSAGES_OUT
1  2014-04-24 12:31:33  Test message outbound
2  2014-04-24 19:16:15  Another test message outbound
```

Then I want the output to be:

```
2014-04-24 12:26:33  Test message inbound
2014-04-24 12:31:33  Test message outbound
2014-04-24 19:12:15  Another test message inbound    
2014-04-24 19:16:15  Another test message outbound
```

I've attempted the query below but I'm getting error that my ORDER BY is an unknown column:

```
SELECT i.receivedDate, i.message
FROM MESSAGES_IN i
UNION
SELECT sentDate, o.message
FROM MESSAGES_OUT o
ORDER BY receivedDate, sentDate;
```

Thank you!

Comment: just write `ORDER BY receivedDate`, without `sentDate` because is the same column results.

Comment: You probably want `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL will use the column names from the first query when using `UNION`, so just use the first query's column name in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT i.receivedDate, i.message
FROM MESSAGES_IN i
UNION ALL
SELECT o.sentDate, o.message
FROM MESSAGES_OUT o
ORDER BY receivedDate
```

It's common to use an alias like this to keep the column name meaningfull:

```
SELECT i.receivedDate AS sendreceiveDate, i.message
FROM MESSAGES_IN i
UNION ALL
SELECT o.sentDate, o.message
FROM MESSAGES_OUT o
ORDER BY sendreceiveDate
```

Also, you probably want `UNION ALL` to avoid losing duplicate rows in the results.

Answer (score 0):

Since column names are different, you can use "ORDER BY 1" which means first column.

```
(SELECT i.receivedDate as messageDate, i.message
FROM MESSAGES_IN i )
UNION
( SELECT o.sentDate as messageDate, o.message
FROM MESSAGES_OUT o )
ORDER BY 1
```

I believe MySQL can use the alias in this case too, so you can replace "1" with messageDate.